# directional vector of given line

Tags: vector-spaces

i know that if line  equation is given by the following

```
      `r={a1*x+b*y+c1*z+d=0 and a2*x+b2*y+c2*z+d2=0`}
```

then directional vector is given by the cross product  of this two plane or it is  determinant of the following form

```
 i   j  k
a1   b1 c1
a2   b2  c2
```

i was trying to  determine   directional vecotor of r which is determined by the  following form

```
 r={y=2;3x-(3)^(1/2)*z=0}
```

but my result  did not match to solution  in  source,there  directional vector is determined like this `r={x=3^(1/2)*lambda`(i can't  write lambda directly from my keyboard),`y=2;and z=3*(lambda)`  and `U_r={3^(1/2),0,3)`  please help me(U_r is a directional vector)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you either didn't plug in the correct values or your only issue is with the arithmetic of a determinant. After inspection the coefficients are: $$(a_1,b_1,c_1)=(0,1,0);$$ $$ (a_2,b_2,c_2)=(3,0,-\sqrt{3}).$$ The (pseudo)determinant that gives the cross product is therefore $$\begin{vmatrix}\mathbf{i} & \mathbf{j} & \mathbf{k} \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 3 & 0 & -\sqrt{3} \end{vmatrix} = \left[(1)(-\sqrt{3})-0\cdot 0\right]\mathbf{i}-\left[(0)(-\sqrt{3})-3\cdot 0\right]\mathbf{j}+\left[ 0\cdot 0-3\cdot 1 \right]\mathbf{k} $$ $$=(-\sqrt{3},0,-3).$$

The negative sign is superfluous so it can be taken out and we arrive at the solution in the source.

Comment: For some reason \left[\right] ends up looking like the floor function. That might be an inherent issue with the renderer or just with my browser or something, I dunno.

Comment: yes it is right my wrong action was that instead of  1 in first column of matrix i have wrote 2   thanks very much

Comment: Hmm, wouldn't $\det$ be superfluous if you're using $|\cdot|$ already?